# Как достать путь файла из диалогового окна открытия файла через Python?

Tags: python, файлы

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы программа открывала диалоговое окно открытия файла, и когда пользователь выбирает файл, в переменную сохраняестя его путь.
Какую библиотеку можно использовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из библиотеки tkinter диалоговое окно filedialog, функция askopenfilename() сохранит вам путь до выбранного файла.

Comment: Спасибо большое!